# default value for size attribute in @page element

Tags: html, css

I have a css code like this

```
@page{
size: "size for A4"
margin: "some values"
}
```

it work fine. But when size attribute is given empty the page size differs from A4.
what is the default value taken for the size attribute when it is empty?

Comment: It's kind of you missed some information in the value section, please provide the real or sample example. 
based on doc here it can be one of these https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size

Comment: `@page{
size: 
margin: 0.44in 0.44in 0.44in 0.44in
}`
in this what is the value taken for size attribute.

Comment: It's wrong, it should be just one title like A4 or two value for Width and Height including unit identifies. but if you want to set the margins just remove or finish the size: from the beginning @page{ size: A4; margin: 0.44in 0.44in 0.44in 0.44in; }

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
@page{ 
  size: A4; 
  margin: 0.44in 0.44in 0.44in 0.44in; 
}
```